# How to search by keyword in Clarifai API

Tags: clarifai

Is it possible to search images by keywords? I want to search by model genereted tags. In Docs there are only 2 options by concept and by image.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link on [how to search images by generated concepts](https://www.clarifai.com/developer/guide/searches#searches) (tags are called concepts).

It's possible to search both by concepts that were automatically added to an image by a model, or by concepts that you yourself have added to an image (i.e. custom concepts).

Additionally, you can add any custom metadata to an image in the form of JSON (e.g. `{"name": "John", "address": {"city": "New York City", "state": "NY"}`, and later search by that (e.g. search images containing metadata `{"address": {"state": "NY"}}`.